# Unit tests in Swift. Is it enough to cover 100%?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, test-coverage

My question is, is it enough to write tests while Xcode will show you 100% coverage and writing tests only for methods what Xcode shows you in coverage calculation screen?

Or I have to write more tests than it shows in the coverage section?
Please look at the screenshots. So there are 12 methods in the list. Is that means that I have to write 12 test, cover them with 100% and stop or I have to think about other tests even I've reached 100% coverage?

[image]

Comment: When testing, you are implicitly only testing the code paths corresponding to the arguments you provide. If you have the line `array[index]`, and you only ever pass one value of `index`, you've covered every path (there's only one) but are likely missing test cases (what if `index < 0`, etc).

Comment: @BallpointBen so there is no formula, right? I have to by myself think about different scenarios and test them?

Comment: Correct. 100% code coverage is a *minimum* requirement

Comment: Thank you, @BallpointBen! Could you please help me with this test? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277922/why-unit-test-only-sometimes-fails-in-swift

Comment: Correct, @J.Doe you need to think about different scenarios when you write your tests, and if you really want to know your tests are good and up to the job you should write them first. TDD for the win.